# No sourcemap for CSS

Tags: sass, configuration, jekyll

I have just upgraded to Jekyll 4.0.0 which includes its own `sass`.

Previously, `sass` uses `sourcemap=none` by default.

Now, `sass` uses `sourcemap=auto` by default (and `auto` defaults to `true`).

**How can I disable generation of `sass` sourcemaps?**

I expected one of the following to disable `sass` sourcemaps:

*_config,yml*

```
sass:
  sourcemap: none
```

*_config,yml* (using flag for newer versions of `sass`)

```
sass:
  no-source-map: true
```

The strange thing is if I change the value in the key-value pair to an invalid argument, I get an error message from `sass` (as expected). This must mean the arguments in the config files above are correct, but not being used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jekyll Sass Converter has updated their Github readme after a request was made 7 days ago I believe.

Excerpt from release:

**`sourcemap`**

Controls when source maps shall be generated.

- `never` — causes no source maps to be generated at all.
- `always` — source
  maps will always be generated.
- `development` — source maps will only be
  generated if the site is in development [environment](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/environments/). That is, when
  the environment variable JEKYLL_ENV is set to development.

Defaults to `always`.

The info can be found here: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sass-converter#source-maps